# Refresh map after removing marker from array

Tags: openlayers-2, markers, array

I have a map an arrays of markers.  This code:

```
function RemoveRedMarker(siteID) {
            
            for (var x in arrRedMarkers) {
             
            if (arrRedMarkers[x].SiteID == siteID) {
                    markers.removeMarker(arrRedMarkers[x]);
                    arrRedMarkers.splice(x, 1);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

will remove the required marker from the array, I can check this in Firebug, however the map doesn't refresh to reflect the removed marker.  How do I update the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removeMarker method is the one you want to remove marker from the map. It is a Markers Layer method and will automatically affect the map.

To test that go to the [OpenLayers Markers example page](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/markers.html) and simply paste the following code in the firebug console:

```
map.layers[2].removeMarker(map.layers[2].markers[0])
```

In your example, if markers is really the OpenLayers.Layer.Markers object that is your map object, it should work. The other thing is that arrRedMarkers[x] must be the same object that is in your layer and not a copy of it.

In your case, instead of keeping a separate array of marker, you could simply access:
    markers.markers
which contains all markers in your Markers layer (untested):

```
function RemoveRedMarker(siteID) {

    for (var x in markers.markers) {

        if ( markers.markers[x].SiteID == siteID) {
            markers.removeMarker(markers.markers[x]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in recent version of OpenLayers, you can do everything the Markers are doing with Vector layers. The support for Vector layer is a lot easier and the tools are much more powerful. See the examples for vector layer to get an idea of how it works:
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/

Comment: your first link is dead.

Comment: The linked changes when OL3 became the official version. Those examples use OL2. Fixed now.